# Como resolver conflito "The source branch is n commits behind the target branch"

Tags: git, gitlab

Tenho um projeto no gitlab e agora eu quero que a minha branch **master** receba tudo da branch **develop**.
Então eu criei um **MR** (Merge Request): `Request to merge develop into master`

Porem o gitlab me fala que eu tenho esse conflito: ***The source branch is 10 commits behind the target branch*** (A branch de origem está 10 commits atrás da branch de destino).

Eu sei que a branch de origem é minha **develop** e a de destino é a **master**. Mas o que significa de fato minha branch develop estar com commits "atrás" da branch master?

- existe uma ou mais branchs, que somam 10 commits que entraram na master sem entrar na develop?
- Ou o contrario? Por algum motivo, existem 10 commits que estão na develop mas o MR nao está contemplando para incluir na master?

Qual o comando git que eu consigo ver quais são esses 10 commits? Como posso resolver esse conflito de uma maneira segura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A explicação é que alguém (você mesmo ou outra pessoa) realizou 10 commits na sua branch `master`, após você ter criado a branch `develop`, que se encontra agora desatualizada.

A solução é atualizar a branch `master` na sua máquina e integrar as modificações na sua branch `develop`, antes de fazer o MR (eu uso `rebase` pra isso, mas pode ser feito com `merge` também), resolvendo possíveis conflitos (arquivos que foram modificados na `master`, já comitados, e também na sua branch `develop`).

`git fetch origin master; git rebase master/develop`

Uma boa prática é atualizar a branch na qual está trabalhando com as atualizações mais recentes da `master` (de tempos em tempos, a depender da necessidade, da produtividade do time, etc.). São os mesmos comandos para essas atualizações frequentes.